# Primefaces Datatable post contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

i am new to primefaces and have no idea how to implement posting data to managedbean from datatable. DataTable cell is html5 div with enabled contenteditable. I would like to post cell data on blur event. Can somebody help me with this problem?

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="workRecordItems"
    var="wrItem"
    value="#{workRecordBean.workRecordItems}"
    style="margin-top:20px;"
    styleClass="workrecord-item-data-table"
    editable="true"
    editMode="cell">
        <p:column headerText="Opis">
            <p:outputPanel styleClass="workrecord-item-data-table-content" pt:contenteditable="true">#{wrItem.note}</p:outputPanel>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Od" width="80">            
            <p:outputPanel styleClass="workrecord-item-data-table-content" pt:contenteditable="true" style="text-align:center;">#{wrItem.fromString}</p:outputPanel>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Do" width="80">
            <p:outputPanel styleClass="workrecord-item-data-table-content" pt:contenteditable="true" style="text-align:center;">#{wrItem.toString}</p:outputPanel>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Čas" width="80">
            <p:outputPanel styleClass="workrecord-item-data-table-content" pt:contenteditable="true" style="text-align:center;">#{wrItem.timeDiffString}</p:outputPanel>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Zar." width="60">         
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox style="margin-left:15px;margin-top:2px;" value="#{wrItem.billing}"/>
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: can you add managedbean code ?

Comment: `I would like to post cell data on blur event` but which for component blur event do you mean ?

Comment: blur on outputpanel. This panel is editable and after blur i would like set value to item property. GetWorkRecordItems method returns list ob WorkRecordItem items.

Comment: You need to walk thru the basics of JSF first. Take a look at the [JSF wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) for starters